# How do i update the Postgres table when job got manually cancelled by the user in databricks

Tags: postgresql, databricks, job-scheduling, cancellation

How do i update the Postgres table when job got manually cancelled by the user in databricks.

i need to update the postgres table status and close the cursor and close the connection when job got cancelled manually or when manually clicked on cancel run button in databricks workflow job  from user in databricks.

i tried with adding keyboard exception block. but it is not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.